# Scraping Contact Information from Several Unique Sites with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'd like to scrape contact info from about 1000-2000 different restaurant websites. Almost all of them have contact information either on the homepage or on some kind of "contact" page, but no two websites are exactly alike (i.e., there's no common pattern to exploit). How can I reliably scrape email/phone # info from sites like these without specifically pointing the Python script to a particular element on the page (i.e., the script needs to be structure agnostic, since each site has a unique HTML structure, they don't all have, e.g., their contact info in a "contact" `div`).

I know there's no way to write a program that will be 100% effective, I'd just like to maximize my hit rate.

Any guidance on this—where to start, what to read—would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the regular expressions module of python.
You can write a simple expression like:

```
re.search(u"\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}",string)
```

and find any standard formatted phone number string (for US numbers).
It looks like gibberish but it should make web scraping infinitely easier once you do.
Here's a decent introductory tutorial:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

I would also highly recommend Selenium for web scraping if you run into too many dynamic web pages:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

Comment: Great, thanks. If there are no email/phone matches on the homepage, what's the best way to find the site's contact page? Just look for links on the page with "contact" in them? Since I'm going to be running this script on up to 2000 different sites, I don't want to be searching through every anchor element necessarily (unless that's the only way to do it), just to save time/keep the program from crashing. Any ideas?

Comment: Hopefully most of them will have it on the home page like you said (it would be kind of stupid of they didn't). I'd recommend searching just the home pages first, then pages with "contact" in the link text (you can use BeautifulSoup to get those). After, you can deal with the problem sites on an individual basis - you should only have 100 or so if I had to guess.

Answer (score 1):

In most countries the telephone number follows one of a very few well defined patterns that can be matched with a simple regexp - likewise email addresses have an internationally recognised format - simply scrape the homepage, contacts or contact us page and then parse with regular expressions - you should easily achieve better than 90% accuracy.

Alternatively of course you simply submit the restaurant name and town to the local equivalent of the Yellow Pages web site.